# Removing special characters from string variable in Stata

Tags: stata, data-manipulation

I am trying to remove special characters from the variable below:

```
dataex issue_type
```

```
"إثبات ملكية_x000d_منع معارضة واثبات ملكية_x000d_"                                                                                                           
"منع معارضة واثبات ملكية_x000d_"                                                                                                                                       
"تقسيم الأموال المشتركة المنقولة وغير المنقولة - إزالة الشيوع_x000d_"
```

So I ran the following code:

```
destring issue_type, gen(new_issue_type) ignore("x000d")
```

However, no new variable is generated and I keep getting the following response:

```
issue_type: contains characters not specified in ignore(); no generate
```

Comment: You're trying to convert that variable to numeric. I can't see **any** numeric characters in your example except the zeros you're removing, and as the error message implies, you would need to specify all the non-numeric characters in any case. Just possibly you want something more like `replace issue_type = subinstr(issue_type, "x000d", "", .)`.

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Try the `sieve()` function: it will strip out spaces and all special characters retaining only the alpha numerics:

```
egen new_issue_type=sieve(issue_type), keep(a n)
```